# how get item from each cell in grid

Tags: grid, extjs3

I have form with `grid`. I defined `dataStore with 2 columns (text and checkBox)`. `Grid.store = defined dataStore.` Second column is `editable` (you can change selection on each checkBox). I have some button, and when I click it, I want to get info about each cell. Example if have gird:

```
Name1     true
Name2     false
```

I want get info `col[0].row[0] is equal 'Name1', col[0].row[1] is equal 'Name2'.`

I try iterate on `dataStore` but it has only value which I put them by hand. The value which was changed on grid by clicking on checkBox didn't save in dataStore.. My question is how to iterate on grid, how get info about each cell.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate across a store in Ext3, you can use `dataStore.each()`

Supply it an anonymous function and the parameter it receives will be the current record in the store. The data in the current record can be read by using `record_var.get(field_name)`.

So, for example:

```
var dataStore = myGrid.getStore();
dataStore.each(function(rec){
    alert(rec.get(field1));
}
```